# Is there a way to draw a route on Bing Map in Metro Style Applications?

Tags: dictionary, styles, microsoft-metro, routes, bing

i would like to draw a route on a Bing Map based on the routing infomation i got from REST service - locations of ItineraryItems. Is there a way to do it? I am using Bing Map SDK für Metro Style Apps.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Set the parameter routepathoutput=points in the query to get a list of points for the routepath with which you can draw the route.